# SQLAlchemy.declarative and deferred column loading

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

is it possible to specify some columns in the SQLAlchemy to be deferred-loading? I am using the sqlalchemy.ext.declarative module to define my mapping, example:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class SomeClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'some_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name =  Column(String(50))
```

I want for example the column name be lazy loaded, how can I accomplish that?

Thank you
Jan

Comment: What are the reasons you might want to defer loading? Are you willing to change the Model or DB schema to make it work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just add `deferred()` around the column declaration:

```
class SomeClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'some_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name =  deferred(Column(String(50)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not define the mapping for the columns which you want to load on demand. Then configure those as described in the [Deferred Column Loading](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/mappers.html#deferred-column-loading) using `mapper` object. Modified code here:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class SomeClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'some_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    #big_name = Column(String(500))

SomeClass.__table__.append_column(Column('big_name', String(500)))
SomeClass.__mapper__.add_property('big_name', deferred(SomeClass.__table__.c.big_name))
```

Running this test code:

```
c = session.query(SomeClass).first()
# here SQL is loading all configured properties, but big_name
print "c: ", c
# only here another SQL request is made to load the property
print "big_name: ", c.big_name
```

produces log extract:

```
... INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...77d0 SELECT some_table.id AS some_table_id, some_table.name AS some_table_name 
FROM some_table 
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0

... INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...77d0 SELECT some_table.big_name AS some_table_big_name 
FROM some_table 
WHERE some_table.id = ?
```